# Are signed binary representations portable between architectures?

Tags: c++, c, x86, arm

I would like to send signed integers across a network in a character stream, and/or save them to disk in a portable binary representation.

Is the ordinary binary representation that gets stored in memory when I assign a variable (I'm using long long, which is 64 bits, signed), considered to be portable between different machine architectures and operating systems?

For example, is the binary representation of a signed negative long long integer the same on an ARM machine as on an x86 machine, and if so, is it considered good/acceptable practice to take advantage of the fact?

Edit: We're already addressing the issue of byte order by using integer operations to deconstruct the integer into chars from the LSB side. My question is whether the *2's complement signed representation* is consistent across architectures.

Comment: In general no - use htonl, htons, ntohl, ntohs to convert values between host and network byte order.

Comment: http://commandcenter.blogspot.se/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Answer (score 3):

In short: **NO**, you cannot rely on binary compatibility across architectures. Different host machines use different byte orders (that's called [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)).

To transport numbers over network it's general consent to use big endian format (aka network byte order). If both machines use also big endian format, they'll take advantage of this automatically. For the ARM architecture byte orders need to be converted.

To convert from network to host byte order and vice versa you can use the `ntohl()`, `ntohs()`,`htonl()`,`htons()` function family from `arpa/inet.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Integers are not "portable by design" in C/C++; you might encounter [endianness](http://www.google.com/search?q=endianness) issues. This is *unrelated* to them being signed or unsigned.

If you are writing this software, make sure to send your integers in a **known** byte order. The receiving part needs to read them in the same order, performing an endianness conversion when necessary.

Comment: I'd also strongly recommend sending unsigned integers too, and you can perform an unsigned-to-signed conversion on the receiving end (which might turn out to be a no-op)

Comment: I'm already addressing the endianness by deconstructing the integer one byte at a time into unsigned chars from the LSB side. My main concern is whether I should be making the integer positive and doing the 2's complement conversion explicitly.

Comment: @dwk: once you've dealt with endianness the answer is "in theory no, in practice yes". C and C++ permit two's complement, ones' complement and sign-magnitude representations of signed integers. In practice everyone uses two's complement, especially everyone connected to the internet. So your protocol definition needs to make clear that it's two's complement and so might require special handling, but you'll never actually have to do the special handling.

Comment: Note that if you use `int64_t` instead of `long long` then you'd get a guarantee that it's two's complement *and* that it's exactly 64 bits. The only thing you don't get is a guarantee that it exists.